# Azure web apps post swap

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I'm using a deployment slot called `staging` on my Azure web.

My application use some specfic files settings.I would replace these file after swapping.

Is there a way to do a `post-swap` ? I'd like to replace some files `automatically` when the swap is finish ( to put the new settings )

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think that the path of least resistance for you is going to be to use an [Azure DevOps Pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/get-started/what-is-azure-pipelines?view=azure-devops). A pipeline is made up of one or more tasks, and there are lots of tasks to choose from.

You can check out source code from a specific branch, build, publish to a slot, swap slots, and [copy files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/copy-files?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) using scripted pipelines.

Here is a [full list of available tasks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/?view=azure-devops). If you would like to copy files from within a repo from one place to another, just take a look at the [command line task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/command-line?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml). The pipeline runs on a Windows or Linux machine (your choice when you choose a Build Agent), so you can use normal DOS copy commands to move files around.

Comment: azure devops has already a task for copying file within Azure Web APP itself ?

Comment: Yes. See my edits. If you are going to copy files around BEFORE you deploy, you can use the web deploy or zip deploy methods. If you want to move files around after a slot swap, I believe you're going to need to use the FTP upload task.

Comment: the files are in the web app itself

Comment: I think the easiest thing would be to 1. Publish via web deploy to your staging slot. 2. Perform the slot swap. 3. FTP the necessary files from your pipeline files to your production slot. 

If you try to copy files that are already on the Azure web app, I think you'd have to figure out how to do something like a SSH connection. I am unaware of if that is even possible.

Comment: I think , it's not possible , but , azure devops have a task to lanch a webjob to change the settings file in my app ?