# Nightwatch pipeline in Azure Devops CI error

Tags: node.js, azure-devops, nightwatch.js

I am trying to create a pipeline in Azure DevOps for my Nightwatch-Cucumber project. I have everything set, and when I run the tests locally everything is working fine, but when I run the tests in Azure DevOps I get an error. This is the error from the log that I get.
[image: Error log]

This are the tasks that I added

[image: Pipeline tasks]

Can anyone help me with this error and how to make it work

Answer (score 0):

> Error connecting to localhost on port 4445

The possible cause of this issue is that port 4445 of the machine where the agent is located is not open.

Based on the error log, it seems that you are using the Microsoft-hosted agent(ubuntu agent).

You could try the following two methods:

1.You can try to change the connection port to 80. Based on my test, the port 80 is opened by default.

Here is an example:

**nightwatch.json:**

```
"test_settings" : {
    "default" : {
      "launch_url" : "http://localhost",
      "selenium_port"  : 80,
      "selenium_host"  : "hub.testingbot.com",
      "silent": true,
      "screenshots" : {
        "enabled" : false,
        "path" : ""
      },

      "skip_testcases_on_fail": false,

      "desiredCapabilities": {
        "javascriptEnabled": true,
        "acceptSslCerts": true
      }
    },
```

2.Since this project could work fine on your local machine, the configuration should be correct on your local machine. So you could try to create a [Self-hosted agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#install).

Then you could run the pipeline on your local machine.

Comment: hello , i have a question , can you help me please

Comment: i put my question 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66645044/azure-web-apps-post-swap/66679662#66679662

Comment: The question in the link is not related to the current question, I think you can discuss it in your thread. Sorry

Comment: can you please , give me a idea to resolve that in my thread ? thanks

Answer (score 0):

I made it work. I switched to Ubuntu agent and installed chrome latest version and latest jdk. Also I had wrong chromedriver version installed, changed that in package.json file. Now its working fine. Thanks all for your answers.